# Passing ArrayList from Fragment A to Fragment B when user clicked navbar (of Fragment B)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to Android & Fragment please help me. My app is using navbar menu which consists of Home (`HomeFragment`) and History (`HistoryFragment`).

I want to pass ArrayList (`existingRecords`) and a Record object (`todayRecord`) from `HomeFragment` to `HistoryFragment` when user navigate from Home to navbar and click on History. I've configured to send `existingRecords` to `MainActivity` class as below. I don't know how to pass `todayRecord` into the intent.

**HomeFragment.class**:

```
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        //compare if the date of last record is the same as today
        //if same, update today's record
        Log.d(msg, "The onStop() event");
        if(recordExist){
            updateLastRecord(todayRecord);
            Log.d(msg, "existing record updated");
        }
        //if record not found, add new record
        else {
            addRecord(todayRecord);
            Log.d(msg, "New record added");
        }
        sendDataToMainActivity();
    }

    public void sendDataToMainActivity(){
        Log.d("Android: ", "HomeFragment: Sending Data to MainActivity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("existingRecords", existingRecords);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    }
```

I don't know how to call sendReceiveData() when user clicked on History (R.id.nav_history) on navbar menu.

**MainActivity.class**:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_history, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        
        loadAdmob();
    }

    public void sendReceiveData(){
        
        //receive data from HomeFragment
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        existingRecords = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("existingRecords");

        //send data to History fragment
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("existingRecords", existingRecords);
        //set Fragmentclass Arguments
        HistoryFragment fragobj=new HistoryFragment();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
        
    }
```

I've configured HistoryFragment.class to receive data but when I ran the code, bundle is null because I have no way to pass the bundle in MainActivity.

**HistoryFragment.class**:

```
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        historyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HistoryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){
            // handle your code here.

            existingRecords = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("existingRecords");
            txtThisMonthSummary = root.findViewById(R.id.txtThisMonthSummary);
            txtThisWeekSummary = root.findViewById(R.id.txtThisWeekSummary);
            txtThisMonthSummary = root.findViewById(R.id.txtYearSummary);
            Log.d("Android: ", "HistoryFragment: Data received");

            summary = new History(existingRecords);
            txtThisWeekSummary.setText(summary.getWeeklySum());
            txtThisMonthSummary.setText(summary.getMonthlySum());
            txtThisYearSummary.setText(summary.getYearlySum());
        }

        return root;
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_zikir"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_history"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_achievement"
            android:title="@string/menu_history" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_achievement" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use ViewModel in your MainActivity and use the same ViewModel instance in both of your fragments via getActivity().getterFunctionForVoewModel(). If you store your existingRecords and todayrecord in ViewModel both fragments and activity will always have access to up to date values of those variables. This will also allow to observe their values and react upon changes by wrapping them with LiveData. I'sure you can easily find online how to do that and this question might even be a duplicate, if thats not the case

Comment: @Rinat Suggesting ViewModel to someone who is new to technology !!!

Comment: out of curiosity : Aren't you saving the data somewhere for history Fragment? like sqlite or Remote server?

Comment: @kelvin yes in HomeFragment I store existingRecords using SharedPreferences. Can I retrieve it back in HistoryFragment?

Comment: You said records if there are multiple records i would suggest you to use Sqlite , Sharedpreds are for key value pair storage .

Comment: @kelvin I am new, will explore on Sqlite. At the moment, I have stored it using SharedPrefences, using Gson Builder and it works.

Comment: if you are not going to store a lot data that's fine.. so all you need to do is get value of that shared pref and show it in history fragment . can't understand why you want to pass it by intent

Comment: @Rinat thank you for your advise. I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Based on @kelvin feedback, I have managed to retrieve the data from SharedPreferences in HomeFragment. I didn't occur to me that data stored in SharedPreferences can be accessed through any class. *Noob*

Share Preference name/key:

```
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Daily Zikir";
    public static final String RECORDLIST = "Records";
```

Code used to store data, called in HomeFragment:

```
    public void saveRecords(List records){
        SharedPreferences settings;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC);
        builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
        Gson sExposeGson = builder.create();
        String jsonRecords = sExposeGson.toJson(records);
        editor.putString(RECORDLIST, jsonRecords);
        editor.commit();

        Log.d("Android: ",  "Jason string saved: "+ jsonRecords);

    }
```

Code used to retrieve data, called in HistoryFragment:

```
    public ArrayList loadRecords() {
        // used for retrieving arraylist from json formatted string
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List records;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.contains(RECORDLIST)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(RECORDLIST, null);

            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            builder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC);
            builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
            Gson sExposeGson = builder.create();
            Record[] recordItems = sExposeGson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, Record[].class);
            records = Arrays.asList(recordItems);
            records = new ArrayList(records);
        } else
            return null;
        return (ArrayList) records;
    }
```

Will explore usage of SQLlite & ViewModel moving forward but this will do for now.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but sqllite is really messy and error prone use Room instead. It is annotation based and generates all the boilerplate code for you.

Comment: @Rinat I saw both SQL & Room in the training material. Will get there soon. Thank you for your suggestion.